# Is there a way to break up long string lines in JSON for cleaner formatting?

Tags: javascript, json, string

I am currently working on an assignment for a JavaScript calculator and I used a .json configuration file to access the different prompts.  I was wondering if there is a way to break long cluttered lines of code.  Here is the line in JavaScript and then the line in my JSON file.

JavaScript

```
 prompt('Would you like to perform another calculation?\n' +
     'Please type \'Y\' or \'y\' for Yes. Any other input will be ' +
     'treated as no.');
```

JSON

```
 "continuePrompt": "Would you like to perform another calculation?\n Please type \'Y\' or \'y\' for Yes. Any other input will be treated as no."
```

I want the JSON version to be like the JavaScript version. I have searched for an answer with no luck.  I am wondering if I am just wording it wrong in my searches since this seems like a very beginner problem.

Thanks,

Comment: Not really. JSON is a drop-dead simple way to represent objects; it provides essentially nothing for convenience. That said, you have a generic "yes/no" question and a prompt; these could be broken out. Other formats might be more suitable if you're dead-set on making the file human-writeable (e.g., YAML).

Comment: While json may be verbose, and therefore somewhat human-readable, it's still often not an optimal input format for humans to write.

Comment: Thank you for your quick feedback!